# Combining fields for SQL table primary key?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Can two fields (e.g. ZIPCode & Route) be used to create a primary key?

```
public class RouteInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int ZIPCode { get; set; }
    public string Route { get; set; }
    public int BusinessCount { get; set; }
    public int ApartmentCount { get; set; }
    public int POBoxCount { get; set; }
    public int ResidentialCount { get; set; }    
}
```

There is a 1:many relationship for zipcode:routes. So when the client inputs a zipcode, he gets back a list of routes in that zipcode such as:

```
B001
B002
B003
...
C001
C002
C005
```

Can these be combined with the zipcode to generate a primary key? For example:

```
21001B001
21001B002
21001B003
...
21001C001
21001C002
21001C005
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a compound primary key with zipcode and route as separate values, but it gets tricky when you store them together. I don't know much about the valid zip codes and routes you need to work with, but you might (or not) get 2 (or more) different combinations of zip codes with routes for the same resulting code

For example:

- Zip `21001` with route `B001`.
- Zip `2100` with route `1B001`.

I would try to store them separately, or even better use a surrogate (auto-increment) numeric value as primary key. This may solve future problems like for example what would happen when a route changes it's code? Suddenly route B001 was updated and it's now G023. You will need to update it's primary key value, and all foreign keys related to it. Same would happen with zip codes. Also zip codes might repeat across different countries (like Israel and USA).